# Best OCR approach on documents with different formats to find one specific information

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computer-vision, image-recognition, ocr

*Unfortunately, because of confidential data, I can't give a more specific explanation.*

### The Problem

So I've got a few documents that in general contain the same information but have different formats. In most cases, the value I am looking for is near a keyword on the document. The OCR itself is taken care of by the Google Cloud Vision API but what is the best approach to handle the different formats?

### My idea

... was to train a classifier that detects what format I am dealing with and then picks the appropriate way of finding the target value, I implemented beforehand by hand. This is not handy nor scalable. So I am looking for some algorithm I tell e.g. where the target value is, what it looks like etc.

What is the best ML-approach for this problem or what are your ideas?

***As an example of the type of data:*** Let's say I have receipts from 20 different supermarkets and I am looking to find the total cost, with the problem that every companies receipt looks different.